# Can I insert a raw XML string using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to read an XML file. I store some of the information from the text nodes in a hash, which I then use to write a new XML file with a different ordering of the elements.

However, I have a whole block of the original XML file that I would like to preserve as-is. I store it in a string by calling the "outer_xml" instance method on a Nokogiri reader object:

```
reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(File.open(filename))
reader.each do |r|

  bg = r.outer_xml if r.name=="BuyersGuide"

  # store stuff in hash from rest of doc

end
```

My question is, when I write the new XML doc using the code block below:

```
# Write the new file
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|

  #puts xml.public_methods.sort.join(", ")
  #break

  xml.Data {
    xml.Apps {
      # writing stuff from the hash
    }
  }
end
```

How can I put the raw XML stuff inside the XML file that I'm using Nokogiri Builder to write? It already has elements explicitly in it, so I can't do a call to:

```
xml.BuyersGuide bg
```

Comment: I'd be great if you could also post sample XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the private method `insert` like this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.Data {
    xml.Apps {
      xml.__send__ :insert, Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('<foo>bar</foo>')
      xml.__send__ :insert, existing_xml_element
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, I couldn't figure out how to call that private method. It works.

Comment: I wish there was an API to manage it without calling a private method.  There is probably some deeper reasoning behind keeping this private.

Comment: ...so don't call it without knowing that deeper reason! Using `send` to break encapsulation can be dangerous.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser - I agree fully. I think in this context, it should be ok, since other methods like `text` internally do the same thing, i.e. generate a text node (which is actually a document fragment) and use `insert` to add to the builder.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using public methods (I read the accepted answer but was uncomfortable using private methods):

```
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.Data {
    xml.Apps {
      xml << '<foo>bar</foo>'
    }
  }
end.to_xml
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
  <Apps>
    <foo>bar</foo>
  </Apps>
</Data>
```